# Custom VBA search and update form

Tags: excel, forms, vba, search

I am trying to create a custom search form and I can't figure out how to search the entire workbook and export different cells value from the line where the value was found to different textbox in the form.

Here is the code I started working from:

```
Private Sub TextBox_Find_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
'Calls the FindAllMatches routine as user types text in the textbox

    Call FindAllMatches

End Sub

Private Sub Label_ClearFind_Click()
'Clears the find text box and sets focus

    Me.TextBox_Find.Text = ""
    Me.TextBox_Find.SetFocus

End Sub

Sub FindAllMatches()
'Find all matches on activesheet
'Called by: TextBox_Find_KeyUp event

Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindWhat As Variant
Dim FoundCells As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim arrResults() As Variant
Dim lFound As Long
Dim lSearchCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long

    If Len(f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value) > 1 Then 'Do search if text in find box is longer than 1 character.

        Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

        FindWhat = f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value
        'Calls the FindAll function
        Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                                FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
        If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 10)
            arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
        Else
            'Add results of FindAll to an array
            ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 10)
            lFound = 1
            For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
                arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
                arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(2).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 3) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(4).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 4) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(5).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 5) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(6).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 6) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(7).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 7) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(17).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 8) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(18).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 9) = FoundCell.EntireRow.Cells(19).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 10) = FoundCell.Address
                lFound = lFound + 1
            Next FoundCell
        End If

        'Populate the listbox with the array
        Me.ListBox_Results.List = arrResults

    Else
        Me.ListBox_Results.Clear
    End If

   End Sub

   Private Sub ListBox_Results_Click()
   'Go to selection on sheet when result is clicked

   Dim strAddress As String
   Dim l As Long

    For l = 0 To ListBox_Results.ListCount
        If ListBox_Results.Selected(l) = True Then
            strAddress = ListBox_Results.List(l, 9)
            ActiveSheet.Range(strAddress).Select
            GoTo EndLoop
        End If
    Next l

EndLoop:

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Close_Click()
'Close the userform

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

The idea is to be able to update line information within the form.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do from what I can see is loop through each worksheets range that you need to find what you are looking for. Something like this below will loop through each sheets used range like you have done in you code for a single sheet,

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SearchRange As Range


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       For Each SearchRange In ws.UsedRange.Cells
         'do your stuff
          Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, ..... 
         'do more stuff            
       Next SearchRange
    Next ws
```

But, be careful doing this, b/c if each range is big it could take a while. If that is the case, loading the data into memory and looping through it there would be much faster.

Also, I would be wary of naming a variable `SearchRange` as it could cause some confusion, maybe something like `srchRange` or something similar.